# Bubble letter with round background color

Tags: fonts, background, rounding, custom-font

I can't remember my login so made this one temp. I have a simple span that creates a bubble letter of a specific color, and I mean it makes a round bullet with the letter cut out. Now most of the letters I can just show through to the background color of white but one of them I need the bg to be black. That being said here's my code.

```
<span class="arr">R</span>

.arr {
font-family: "Bullet";
color: #ffda00;
background-color: black;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Now it shows up fine except the black peaks out on either side of the bubble. I've tried background-size, width, a negative border width, and the browser just seems to ignore padding. I have also tried display:block;float:left; and display:inline-block;

Does anyone have any suggestions?

I kinda fixed it but am still looking for a better way. I nested a div with the bubble letter and applied a background color to that. But I still need a way to have it scale to the letter automatically.

```
<span class="arr"><div class="bgb"></div>R</span>
```

and the css

```
.arr {
font-family: "Bullet";
color: rgb(232, 206, 53);
position: relative;
margin-left: -1px;
}

.bgb {
width: 41px;
height: 41px;
display: inline-block;
background-color: black;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
margin: 7px;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```